# How to get Universal Windows Platform (UWP) application symbolicated crash reports?

Tags: win-universal-app, crash-reports, crash-dumps, windows-10-universal, symbolicatecrash

For a live/testing Universal Windows Platform(UWP) application how I can get crash reports? Is there any SDK for UWP, Like for iOS/Android platform [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) provide symbolicated report about an application crash.

**Following Details I want in a crash report**
1. **Device Details** - like Device Name, Model etc
2. **OS Version**
3. **File Name** - In which app crash
4. **Line Number** - In which app crash
5. **Parents Method** - Parents Method of method in which app crash
6. **Other threads details**

I want something similar to `Crashlytics SDK`, like for iOS. Here the screenshot one of my `iOS` application which contains crash details
[image]

Comment: Hockeyapp will support symbolicated crash reports soon, they said so.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you may use [Hockeyapp](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb), you may merge Hockeyapp SDK to your app, it will help you collect crash report and some other things. HockeySDK.UWP is in process now, you may use HockeySDK.WINRT instead. Here is the [link](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/hockeyapp-for-windows-store-apps-and-windows-phone-store-apps).

Answer (score 0):

[Hockeyapp](http://hockeyapp.net/) for UWP is in "preseason" so currently in development but available for users already.

just sign up for Hockeyapp with a free accound and apply for "preseason" you'll get access to UWP and other beta features in a few days. (at least I received access quite fast on multiple accounts)

when you have access it's just adding this nuget package: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/HockeySDK.UWP

Microsoft Application Insights also has some good functionality for this but it's [deprecated](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-get-started/) since last month where Microsoft tells you to move to Hockeyapp